# WPF MVVM Listview itemsource binding with list in a class property

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, master-detail

I have a page with two parts : 
A Listview with itemsource binded with a class, ObservableCollection "Patients" loaded with "Patient" class.
Under the Listview are Textboxes binded with the selecteditem Patient. Everything works without writing any code in the page, except in selection_changed to scroll to selected item.

A second Listview must display the details "Visites" from the selected "Patient".

The application works in a MVVM Framework with a Viewmodel containing the properties for the page.

The problem is to make the relation between the two ListView. I tried first building the second list "Visites" in the NotifyPropertyChanged event :

```
            if (Patient.ID > 0)
            {
                LoadVisite(Patient.ID); // fill the details list "Visites"
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Visites");

            }
```

No delail is shown when "Patient" is selected.

I tried another solution inserting the list of details in the master class "Patient like this :

```
    public Class Patient
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<ClsVisite> Visites
    {
        get
        {
            return _visites;
        }
        set
        {
            _visites = value;
        }
    }
            // WDABase class to open the database and load data connection 
            WDABase wd = new WDABase();
            wd.LoadListeVisites(ID, _visites); //ID is the relation beween the two tables


        }

    }
```

Now I try to create the Listview detail itemsource in the XAML like this :

```
     <ListView Name="ListeVisites" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Patient.Visites}" SelectedItem="{Binding Visite}">
```

No details where shown.

The unique solution I found was to add some code in the selection_changed event of the master Listview like this (in this case the listviews are in two different frame) :

```
    private void ListePatients_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListePatients.ScrollIntoView(ListePatients.SelectedItem);
        if(ListePatients.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var w1 = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)App.Current.MainWindow.Content).Parent;
            Frame pageVisite = (w1 as MainWindow).Visit;
            var w2 = (System.Windows.FrameworkElement)pageVisite.Content;
            ListView Lv = (w2 as Visite).ListeVisites;
            Lv.ItemsSource = (ListePatients.SelectedItem as ClsPatient).Visites; 

        }

    }
```

And it's works but is there another elegant solution to bind the itemsource of the details Listview ?
Thanks for helping me.
Jean-Marie

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

The Reason the details were not displayed is because the frame used for the listview is not common with the master frame.
I discover that when I display the details frame the "Patient" object contains only null. I Don't know why but I read about sharing ViewModel and now I use a common one in App.xaml and I Don't need to specify the itemsource for the details Listview in code. I put in XAML itemsource={Binding Patient.Visites} and everything works.